# Focus reverts to text input on first attempt to transfer it to another element; only when VoiceOver is active

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, voiceover

**Note:** *This question is specific to desktop/non-touch keyboard navigation on OS X. The question comes from a use case revealed in QA. The issue was not reported for Windows running NVDA or the like.*

When testing with VoiceOver enabled, attempting to transfer `focus` from the `input` to another element (on the `keyup` event, filtered to the down arrow key), the targeted element gets `focus` for a moment before it immediately returns to the `input` element.

It only does so the first time, though. And only if the input is not empty. After that, everything seems to work as expected.

```js
let
  $results = $('#results');
$(document).on({
  'keyup': event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.which == 40) {
      $results.children().eq(0).focus();
    }
  }
}, '#main');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" id="main">
  <div id="results">
    <p tabindex="0">foo</p>
    <p tabindex="0">bar</p>
    <p tabindex="0">baz</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried same with nvda? does it behave same?

Comment: Negative. I'm hoping this is a known VoiceOver quirk and that someone has encountered it/can verify it.

Comment: Does it happen with both a Mac and iOS (assuming you have a bluetooth keyboard)?

Comment: Also negative. I *can* test that, but keyboard navigation for Mobile device was, honestly, not even on my radar. Until you mentioned it, I hadn't conceived of it as a potential use case.